# Select a class using CSS based on whether or not it has any siblings that share the same class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So, I'm working in a design framework that makes heavy use of line-height for vertical centering. I currently have an absolutely positioned HTML element with vertically centered text/content inside, and when I add another identical element as a sibling, I'd like it to occupy the same space, but change the line-height on each (the first and second) of the siblings to make them raise/lower a bit, to appear as two stacked, vertically centered entities. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">inner alone</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">inner1, move me up a bit!</div>
    <div class="inner">inner2</div>
</div>
```

"inner alone" is vertically centered within its container. "inner1" and "inner2" should be stacked on top of one another, and also vertically centered, via different line heights on each.

I can easily target the second, sibling element ("inner2") and change its line height, using inner+inner, inner:nth-of-child, and more I'm sure. However, how can I target "inner1" and not also "inner alone" using CSS? Is this even possible?

Here is an example to work off of: http://jsfiddle.net/pxc0uug2/

I'm not very interesting in reworking the entire thing. I could figure that out if necessary, however I'm only interested in whether or not I can target "inner1" using nothing but its position and class name, and not also target "inner alone."

Comment: You can, by combining nth-first- and -last of type, but using line height for this is the wrong way to go to begin with. Use transform instead.

Comment: I must be missing something.  Wouldn't `.container:nth-child(1) .inner` work as an inclusive approach, while `.container:not(:nth-child(n+2)) .inner` would work as an exclusive approach?

Comment: The question is reasonable, and the OP gave an example, so why the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target it using

```
.inner:nth-last-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxc0uug2/2/)

Comment: Perfect. Didn't even realize that selector existed.